# How to apply brightness from one image onto another in Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, colors, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a texture using an image with 3 colors, and a [Perlin noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) grayscale image.

This is the original image:

[image: Original Image]

This is the grayscale Perlin noise image:

[image: Grayscale Perlin Image]

What I need to do is apply the original image's brightness to the grayscale image, such that darkest and lightest brightness in the Perlin noise image is no longer 100% black (0) and 100% white (1), but taken from the original image. Then, apply the new mapping of brightness from the grayscale Perlin noise image back to the original image.

This is what I tried:

```
from PIL import Image

alpha = 0.5
im = Image.open(filename1).convert("RGBA")
new_img = Image.open(filename2).convert("RGBA")
new_img = Image.blend(im, new_img, alpha)
new_img.save("foo.png","PNG")
```

And this is the output that I get:

[image: resulting gradient, sort of]

**Which is wrong**, but imagine the dark and light orange and bright color having the same gradient as the grayscale image, BUT with no 100% black or 100% white.

I believe I need to:

1. Convert original image to `HSV` (properly, I've tried with a few functions from `colorsys` and `matplotlib` and they give me weird numbers.
2. Get highest and lowest `V` value from the original image.
3. Convert grayscale image to `HSV`.
4. Transform or normalize (I think that's what its called) the grayscale `HSV` using the `V` values from the original `HSV` image.
5. Remap all the original `V` values with the new transformed/normalized grayscale `V` values.

Comment: Maybe you want to edit your question to make it clearer what the expected outcome would be. Also a clear problem description may help, in how far are the suggested steps not giving you the desired result. Also, making this reproducible for others, see [mcve].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why is it not working?

The approach that you are using will not work as expected because instead of keeping color and saturation information from one image and taking the other image's lightness information (totally or partially), you are just interpolating all the channels from both images at the same time, based on a constant `alpha`, [as stated on the docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.blend):

> `PIL.Image.blend(im1, im2, alpha)`
>
> Creates a new image by interpolating between two input images, using a constant alpha: `out = image1 * (1.0 - alpha) + image2 * alpha`
>
> [...]
>
> alpha – The interpolation alpha factor. If alpha is 0.0, a copy of the first image is returned. If alpha is 1.0, a copy of the second image is returned. There are no restrictions on the alpha value. If necessary, the result is clipped to fit into the allowed output range.

---

#### Basic working example

First, let's get a basic example working. I'm going to use `cv2` instead of `PIL`, just because I'm more familiar with it and I already have it installed on my machine.

I will also use `HSL` (`HLS` in `cv2`) instead of `HSV`, as I think that will produce an output that is closer to what you might be looking for.

```
import cv2

filename1 = './f1.png'
filename2 = './f2.png'

# Load both images and convert them from BGR to HLS:

img1 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(filename1, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(filename2, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)

# Copy img1, the one with relevant color and saturation information:

texture = img1.copy()

# Replace its lightness information with the one from img2:

texture[:,:,1] = img2[:,:,1]

# Convert the image back from HLS to BGR and save it:

cv2.imwrite('./texture.png', cv2.cvtColor(texture, cv2.COLOR_HLS2BGR))
```

This is the final output:

[image]

---

#### ️ Adjust lightness

Ok, so we have a simple case working, but you might not want to replace `img1`'s lightness with `img2`'s completely, so in that case just replace this line:

```
texture[:,:,1] = img2[:,:,1]
```

With these two:

```
alpha = 0.25
texture[:,:,1] = alpha * img1[:,:,1] + (1.0 - alpha) * img2[:,:,1]
```

Now, you will retain `25%` lightness from `img1` and `75%` from `img2`, and you can adjust it as needed.

For `alpha = 0.25`, the output will look like this:

[image]

---

#### `HSL` & `HSV`

Although [`HSL` and `HSV` look quite similar, there are a few differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), mainly regarding how they represent pure white and light colors, that would make this script generate slightly different images when using one or the other:

[image: HSL ColorSolid Cylinder]
[image: HSV ColorSolid Cylinder]

We just need to change a couple of things to make it work with `HSV`:

```
import cv2

filename1 = './f1.png'
filename2 = './f2.png'

# Load both images and convert them from BGR to HSV:

img1 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(filename1, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(filename2, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Copy img1, the one with relevant color and saturation information:

texture = img1.copy()

# Merge img1 and img2's value channel:

alpha = 0.25
texture[:,:,2] = alpha * img1[:,:,2] + (1.0 - alpha) * img2[:,:,2]

# Convert the image back from HSV to BGR and save it:

cv2.imwrite('./texture.png', cv2.cvtColor(texture, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR))
```

This is how the first example looks like when using `HSV`:

[image]

And this is the second example (with `alpha = 0.25`):

[image]

**You can see the most noticeable differences are in the lightest areas.**